# Appium 1.10.0 + iOS : Unable to accept permission alert

Tags: automated-testing, python, appium, mobile-automation, ios

Team,

I am facing issues to accept the permission on iOS using Appium. I have tried below options:

- capabilities.SetCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);
- driver.switch_to_alert()
- driver.findElement(By.id("Allow_buttonID")).click();

Still unable to accept the permission alerts i.e. Unable to tap on "Allow"

**My environment :**

- Mac : 10.14
- Appium : 1.10.0
- Platform : iOS[any version]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution to accept alerts on ios:

```
def acceptAlert(self):

     if Driver.ExecutionPlatform == Platform.iOS:
        if self.isElementPresent("Allow"):
            try:
                Driver.Instance.execute_script('mobile: alert', {'action': 'accept', 'buttonLabel': 'Allow'})
            except:
                print "alert not displayed"
```